# Разноцветный scrollbar + jquery

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Приветствую.

Не подскажите, может, кто встречал в сети плагин JQuery, который бы давал возможность делать скроллбар у блока, как на картинке?

[image: Скролл]

Тут еще важно, что верх от низа отличается и делится бегунком.

очень буду благодарен за наметку.

Comment: @Роман Жуков, [jQuery UI Slider][1]. Градиент по умолчанию там серо-белый, но сделать его цветным - не будет сложно.


  [1]: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical

Только стили свои пропишите для градиента и бегунка

Comment: Спасибо большое - то, что надо.